# controller action for changing status in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, status

I tried to create a actionSuspend in my userController.
But when i click the button to update the status its redirect me to a blank page or the function i created is not working.
This is my Controller code:

```
public function actionSuspend()
    {
        $user_model = \app\models\User::find()
                    ->where(['social_worker'=>'1'])
                    ->one();
        if($user_model == 'suspend'){
            $user_model->social_worker = 'activate';
           return $this->redirect(['index']);

        }
    }
```

and my view code is

```
'suspend' => function($url,$model){
    if($model->social_worker ==1)
        return Html::a('<span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger icon-remove bigger-80"style="margin-left:5px;"></span>', $url,['title'=>Yii::t('app','Revoke social worker')]);
    },
```

Comment: `if($user_model == 'suspend')` is a mistake? Could you add the code that surrounds suspend and activate as well, what is it part from? What can be said is that your action method definitly should contain a render call. Without you get the blank page, of course. Typically it is something like `return $this->render('index');`. And you need to save your model. I guess you should make yourself more familiar with Yii2 and read the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html) first. I think you need a bit more base knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
   if($user_model->status == 'suspend'){
           $user_model->social_worker = 'activate';
           return $this->render(['index']);

    }
```

Comment: i tried this but got an error
strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: public function actionSuspend()
   {

    $user_model = \app\models\User::find()
                    ->where(['user_is_social_worker'=>'1'])
                    ->one();
         if($user_model->user_is_social_worker == 'suspend'){
           $user_model->social_worker = 'activate';
           $user_model->save();
           return $this->render(['index']);
       }
   }
still not working...

Comment: @MohammedIqbal Not surprizing, it needs to be `$this->render('index')`, without braces! Look into the [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#render%28%29-detail) ... That answer is not so useful...

Comment: My answer has just pointed out that you can not compare $ model_user but you need to at least specify a field which I guess is `status` and then you have to compare the $ model_user-> status. since it is not visible on the User class I imagined it to be so. trying to indicate precisely the code of User model.